# HOW VS WHAT; whats grammatically corrrect

Tags: grammar

What's grammatically correct?

this song depicts how you made me feel for the past few months.

or

this song depicts what you made me feel for the past few months.

Comment: They are both acceptable. A third alternative is "the way you made me feel".

Comment: Both sentences seem to express current relevance, so I'd prefer to use the perfect as in "This song depicts how you've made me feel for the past few months".

Comment: *What* might imply a greater level of detail (for instance, happy about *something*, as opposed to just happy in general), but that level of subtlety is not normally considered.